# Running Rapidminer in Node.js or MSSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, stored-procedures, rapidminer

I'm new to rapidminer and would like to ask if there's any way to run rapidminer using node.js or MSSQL stored procedures?

Supposedly, I should run the rapidminer processes for data analytics using my node.js hosted web application, however, I was not able to search/find for a way to do/code this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Using node's [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) api you can run arbitrary commands on the server.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to achieve here. RapidMiner is a standalone data science tool. But if you're running a RapidMiner AI hub (on premise or in a cloud instance), you could use the REST API to trigger process execution:
https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/hub/rest-api/